# Why washing machines drain water continuously during spinning?

Tags: washing-machine

While spinning, washing machines tend to use their drain pump almost all the time. The pump is working all the time with the exception of some short periods (a couple of seconds long).

Actually the drain pump works regardless of the amount of water to be drained.

- At the second half of the spinning cycle less water drops out of the clothes, than in the first half, but the pump works just as hard.
- If you wash only a pair of socks, there is not much water to drain, but the pump works hard.

My questions:

- Why is the drain pump almost always on during spinning?
- Why not turn the drain pump on only when there is some water to drain? This would make the washing more quiet. The wear of the pump would also be reduced.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about home improvement.

Comment: @JACK: I have seen questions here that do not aim to solve, but only to understand something. So this could be reopened. Do you agree? I am so disappointed, that it is closed. I waited for an answer from an engineer/technician.

Comment: @Dr.Gut  I'm sure some slip by but understand that this is a home improvement site for DIYers.  There are forums out there, Yahoo Answers, for this type of question. If we try to answer everything, the site will get bogged down and searching for our purposed answers will be more difficult.  Most of the questions you're referring to are probably about why something's done in the home improvement area and not about why an appliance works a certain way. .....  but I think it just a matter of cost and a cheap, easy part to replace.

Comment: @JACK: Can you delete it then? It doesn't let me to. Thanks.

Comment: Please do NOT completely change the question. There is now an answer that makes absolutely no sense based on how the question currently reads. This isn't the way things are done at the SE sites.

Comment: I restored the original version of the question since that's what someone took the trouble to answer. Please post a new question about using rubber feet for noise reduction.

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to cost.  Including a water level sensor would be extra cost, extra electronics, and more complexity.  This way, they probably piggyback the pump motor onto the same control logic that runs the drum motor.  I doubt that most washer manufacturers care too much about pump wear or noise.  With pumps, and motors in general, much of the wear and tear is starting and stopping, as opposed to run-time, so running it once per drain/spin cycle may actually be less wear on the pump than turning it on/off a few times each cycle.
As long as it makes it past their warranty limit, they don't care past that.

Comment: Sadly, this answer, while perfectly logical for the original question, no longer makes any sense because the original question has been obliterated.